# Migrating issues from Visual Studio Team Services to github

Tags: github, azure-devops

I'm in process of migrating my open source project from VS Team Services to GitHub (in hope of having actual contributors at least).
Migrating git repository was easy, but now I have a problem of migrating issues.

1. I don't know how to migrate issues.
2. I really like Team Services board. Can I get something like this in Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Question 1, there isn't any tool or simple way to migrate the VSTS issues to GitHub as I know since the issues in VSTS are work items that use a totally different template with GitHub. If you have large amount of issues need to be migrated, you may create an application and use [VSTS Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/work-items) and [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) to do this.

For Question 2, GitHub does not provide Kankan board feature by default but you can get it from some other service. For example: [waffle.io](https://waffle.io/)